Struggling with MMonit
I'm trying to use monit on Fedora FC39 and I'm strugling with a particular service I want to monitor
here is the service monit configuration file
CHECK PROGRAM domoticz PATH "/usr/bin/systemctl --quiet is-active domoticz" TIMEOUT 5 SECONDS
     START PROGRAM = "/bin/systemctl start domoticz"
     STOP  PROGRAM = "/bin/systemctl stop domoticz"
     IF FAILED
         ADDRESS 127.0.0.1
         PORT 8080
         PROTOCOL http
         REQUEST "/json.htm?type=command&param=getversion"
     STATUS = 200
     FOR 2 CYCLES
     THEN exec "/bin/systemctl restart domoticz else if succeeded then exec "/var/lib/domoticz/pushover-notification.sh 'domoticz restarted'"
     IF 5 restarts within 5 cycles then exec "/sbin/reboot"

everytime I run monit -t, I get /etc/monit.d/domoticz:4: syntax error 'FAILED'
monit --version
This is Monit version 5.33.0
Built with ssl, with ipv6, with compression, with pam and with large files
Copyright (C) 2001-2022 Tildeslash Ltd. All Rights Reserved.

would appreciate any help, as I really don't understand the issue
I look after stackoverflow for similar problem but no success

Looks like your syntax might be off here:       THEN exec "/bin/systemctl restart domoticz else if succeeded then exec "/var/lib/domoticz/pushover-notification.sh 'domoticz restarted'".. shouldn't that else if be a separate line; ELSE IF. https://lists.nongnu.org/archive/html/monit-general/2016-06/msg00040.html

You can not do this, this way.
From the manual, see https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#CONNECTION-TESTS

Monit can perform connection testing via network ports or via Unix
sockets.  A connection test may only be used within a process or host
service type context.

You use a program check, therefore the connection test is not available, try something like this
CHECK PROGRAM domoticz PATH "/usr/bin/systemctl --quiet is-active domoticz" TIMEOUT 5 SECONDS
     START PROGRAM "/bin/systemctl start domoticz"
     STOP  PROGRAM "/bin/systemctl stop domoticz"
     if status != 0 then
        exec "/var/lib/domoticz/pushover-notification.sh 'domoticz test failed'"
     IF 5 restarts within 5 cycles then exec "/sbin/reboot"

CHECK HOST domoticz_host with address 127.0.0.1
     IF FAILED
         PORT 8080
         PROTOCOL http
         REQUEST "/json.htm?type=command&param=getversion"
     STATUS = 200
     FOR 2 CYCLES
     THEN exec "/usr/local/bin/monit restart domoticz"
       else if succeeded then exec "/var/lib/domoticz/pushover-notification.sh 'domoticz restarted'"

A suggestion only, this should fit to 5.3x.0,
Lutz
